# Bash Script - Compress multiple directories in one archive

Tags: bash, shell

I made a script a while back that would use `zip` to compress several different user specified directories.  The way the script did this is it would read the directories from `config.txt` and compress each one individually.  It just so happens that, for my uses, all of these directories are in the same parent.  For instance, I'll have the following directories in my `/Users/username/` directory:

```
Desktop
Documents
Pictures
```

Is there a way to combine these 3 in the same archive?

For a reference, here is my current script:

```
BKUPDATE="/Users/michaelgarrison/Backup/BKUP_"$(date +%Y)-$(date +%m)-$(date +%d)

# Create the Backup directory if it does not exist
mkdir -p $BKUPDATE

# File where directories are specified
CONFIG="config.txt"

while read SOURCE
do
    DESTINATION="/Users/michaelgarrison/"
    OUTPUT=$BKUPDATE"/Backup_"$SOURCE"_"$(date +%Y)-$(date +%m)-$(date +%d)".zip"
    (cd /Users/michaelgarrison/; zip -r $OUTPUT $SOURCE)
done < $CONFIG
```

Comment: Unrelated tip: you only need one call to `date`: `date +"%Y-%m-%d"`

Comment: Just call `zip -r $OUTPUT Desktop Documents Pictures`?

Comment: I didn't realize that I could just add more directories to the command.  I went along with @Hayden and created an array to display each directory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`zip -r backup Desktop/* Documents/* Pictures/*`

That would compress all the files under Desktop, Documents and Pictures under a file named `backup.zip`

The trick of sorts would be reading the list from the config.txt file, presumably a vertical list or array and making it one long string.

Comment: I didn't know you could just add directories to the command like that.  What I did was stored each value in an array when it is passed through the loop and then used `(cd $DPATH; zip -r $OUTPUT ${DIR[*]})` to zip the directories.

Answer (score 1):

please read the comments and answers, they answered your question in a good way!!

- put constant things out of the loop

> OUTPUT="/Users/michaelgarrison/"$BKUPDATE"/Backup_"$(date
>   +"%Y-%m-%d")".zip"
>       DESTINATION="/Users/michaelgarrison/" <--------- do you need this? I think you don't
>
> ```
> while read SOURCE
> do
>     zip -r $OUTPUT $SOURCE
> done < $CONFIG
> ```

If you want to do this more than once, you may can use [rsync](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/rsync)

Comment: I did read the answers and comments, and I've been working on the script and getting everything working before I commented or accepted anything.

Comment: Speaking of doing things in a "good" way, your answer is basically the same as my own answer except for the fact that you moved the `DESTINATION` outside of the loop.  I also didn't accept my answer yet because I wanted to see if other people had ideas on how I should do this.

Comment: i changed the `DESTINATION`, the directory change, because it's every time the same and the `date`, I thought you didn't the see comment below your question (and yes, my answer can be deleted, if you take your code ;))

Comment: I only posted my answer because I discovered it by accident.  I knew that it wasn't really good and looking back now I see that the way I had `DESTINATION` declared wasn't proper.  I wound up going with @Hayden because he, as well as @vonbrand, brought to my attention the fact that you can just add directories to `zip`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just answered my own question, but instead of deleting I'll leave it here for future reference.  What I did was change the output to the same zip file for each pass.

What I did was change:

```
while read SOURCE
do
    DESTINATION="/Users/michaelgarrison/"
    OUTPUT=$BKUPDATE"/Backup_"$SOURCE"_"$(date +%Y)-$(date +%m)-$(date +%d)".zip"
    (cd /Users/michaelgarrison/; zip -r $OUTPUT $SOURCE)
done < $CONFIG
```

to:

```
OUTPUT=$BKUPDATE"/Backup_"$(date +%Y)-$(date +%m)-$(date +%d)".zip"
while read SOURCE
do
    DESTINATION="/Users/michaelgarrison/"
    (cd /Users/michaelgarrison/; zip -r $OUTPUT $SOURCE)
done < $CONFIG
```

Comment: I know this isn't technically a "good" way to do it, but it does work.